# Java - Spring: dependency injection across bean factories in SingletonBeanFactoryLocator?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following scenario:

1) two xml configuration files, say `foo.xml` and `bar.xml`. They contain `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` beans with names `fooFactory` and `barFactory` resp. Each bean in turn is given its own xml configuration file through its constructor,

2) client code uses`SingletonBeanFactoryLocator` and methods `getInstance` and `useBean` to get these factories. E.g. `SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.getInstance("classpath:foo.xml").useBeanFactory("fooFactory");`

Requirement: some beans in barFactory need to access some beans in fooFactory.

The current solution is to get a reference to fooFactory through `SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.getInstance("classpath:foo.xml").useBeanFactory("fooFactory");` and the use `getBean` to get the necessary beans.

Question: is it possible to inject beans from `fooFactory` into beans from `barFactory`, so beans in `barFactory` get these dependencies automatically?

Comment: are maintaining 2 ClassPathXmlApplicationContexts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up defining these factories in the same .xml and chaining them. I then did normal injection of fooFactory beans into barFactory beans.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have a "common" application context xml.

In this file, you can define beans that will be used in both foo and bar. Then you can import this common xml in to both the application contexts.

This approach would create those beans defined in the common xml twice, but this may or may not be a problem. If you want to share the SAME instances you could create the common beans as Singletons.

Comment: Even if we create them as singletons, their singletonness applies only to the context in which they are defined, rt? In this case we have two appContexts, so even if singletons, won't they be created twice?

Comment: Well, they are still going to be executed within the same JVM, so if you create them in the context file using say a factory method it should return the same instance.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you meant singleton-scoped Spring beans.